# Empty rows for MySQL Query but using a WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table names lcMovimientos and what I need is a query where I get as a result the sum of the quantity of cantidadMovimientos but I want each row to be by the day of the week and only to sum the days of the current week, so after researching I found the best way to do this was creating a new table with the days of the week, so I now have a table called diasSemana

```
SELECT * FROM diasSemana
+-----------+
| diaSemana |
+-----------+
|         0 |
|         1 |
|         2 |
|         3 |
|         4 |
|         5 |
|         6 |
+-----------+
```

and a table called lcMovimientos

```
mysql> DESCRIBE lcMovimientos;
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idMovimiento          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| idUsuario             | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| tipoMovimiento        | tinyint(4)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cantidadMovimiento    | decimal(20,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idCategoria           | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fechaMovimiento       | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idCuenta              | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| descripcionMovimiento | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| etiquetasMovimiento   | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I can make a query where I do get the sum of the cantidadMovimiento but when I add the where clause so I only get results from the current week, I no longer get the rows by day fo the week, so here is my query:

```
mysql> SELECT SUM( cantidadMovimiento ) , diaSemana, fechaMovimiento                                                                                                    -> FROM diasSemana
    -> LEFT JOIN lcMovimientos ON diaSemana = WEEKDAY( fechaMovimiento ) 
    -> GROUP BY diaSemana;
+---------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| SUM( cantidadMovimiento ) | diaSemana | fechaMovimiento |
+---------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
|                    280.00 |         0 | 2012-02-20      |
|                    800.00 |         1 | 2012-02-21      |
|                   7000.00 |         2 | 2012-02-29      |
|                      NULL |         3 | NULL            |
|                      NULL |         4 | NULL            |
|                  -3300.78 |         5 | 2012-02-18      |
|                    600.00 |         6 | 2012-02-26      |
+---------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

and when I use the WHERE clause:

```
mysql> SELECT SUM( cantidadMovimiento ) , diaSemana, fechaMovimiento
    -> FROM diasSemana
    -> LEFT JOIN lcMovimientos ON diaSemana = WEEKDAY( fechaMovimiento ) 
    -> WHERE WEEK( fechaMovimiento, 1 ) = WEEK( CURRENT_DATE, 1 ) 
    -> GROUP BY diaSemana;
+---------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
| SUM( cantidadMovimiento ) | diaSemana | fechaMovimiento |
+---------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
|                    265.00 |         0 | 2012-02-20      |
|                    800.00 |         1 | 2012-02-21      |
|                    600.00 |         6 | 2012-02-26      |
+---------------------------+-----------+-----------------+
```

So my question is how can i make a query where I will get the results by the day of the week using the where to only get dates of the current week??? thank you so much in advance!

Comment: **This is because you are aggregating wrong.**  MySQL will return a random  `fechaMovimiento` value per group, so when you filter on it you are getting random results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM( cantidadMovimiento ),0) AS cantidadMovimiento,
    diaSemana,
    DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL diaSemana-WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY) AS weekday
FROM diasSemana
LEFT JOIN lcMovimientos
    ON diaSemana = WEEKDAY( fechaMovimiento ) 
    AND WEEK(fechaMovimiento) = WEEK(NOW()) AND YEAR(fechaMovimiento) = YEAR(NOW())
GROUP BY diaSemana;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but trying this will sum all the values in cantidadMovimiento even the ones that are not on the current week

Comment: did you try it with the WHERE WEEK(fechaMovimiento) = WEEK(NOW()) AND YEAR(fechaMovimiento) = YEAR(NOW()) statement?

Comment: Here is what the query gave me 
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
| cantidadMovimiento | diaSemana | weekday    |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
|             265.00 |         0 | 2012-02-20 |
|             800.00 |         1 | 2012-02-21 |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+    It only gives me the results of the days where I have movement excluding the Sunday

Comment: try to change the from to lcMovimientos and do the diasSemana to the left join  statement (changed in my answer)

Comment: still no good, this is the result  +--------------------+-----------+------------+
| cantidadMovimiento | diaSemana | weekday    |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+
|            4374.22 |      NULL | NULL       |
|             265.00 |         0 | 2012-02-20 |
|             800.00 |         1 | 2012-02-21 |
+--------------------+-----------+------------+

Comment: sorry, changed the tables... try again please

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I have been looking for an answer to this since like 5 days!